# Creating an Image with Text and a Transparent Background with GD PHP

Tags: php, image, gd

Everything works to rotate and center the text in this image, but there is a black border around the text created by the imagecolortransparent function. How can I just create an image with text and a transparent background? Here is the code:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');

$title = "test text";

$im = imagecreatetruecolor(87, 80);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefill($im, 87, 80, $black);
imagecolortransparent($im, $black);

$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$font = "../fonts/arial.ttf";

$bbox = imagettfbbox(12,-40,"../fonts/arial.ttf", $title);
$width = $bbox[2]-$bbox[0];
$height = ceil(($bbox[6]-$bbox[0])/2);

$pos = ceil((87-$width)/2);
$posx = $pos-$height;
$posy = $pos+$height;

imagettftext($im, 12, -45, $posx, $posy, $white, $font, $title);

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to turn off anti-aliasing, using a negative for the colour accomplishes this.

```
imagettftext($im, 12, -45, $posx, $posy, -$white, $font, $title);
```